# How could I compute a map route that goes from a starting point to a destination through optional waypoints?

Tags: algorithm, google-maps, osrm

Let's say I want to plot a navigation route from San Francisco to New York. There are about a thousand services that can do this for free. There are also many services that can solve the Traveling Salesman Problem and compute a route through 6 cities, figuring out the optimal order. These are all solved problems.

Now let's say I want to plot a course from SF to NY, stopping at EV chargers from a database along the way.

This is more difficult than just a bunch of waypoints, because I don't need to stop at every one. I just need to limit my route to hop from one to the next.

How might I go about figuring this out? Is there an algorithm that I can use to simplify this? Or perhaps I could use OSRM (https://github.com/Project-OSRM/osrm-backend) to help me somehow, instead of relying on the public APIs. We could brute-force this and just keep calculating routes until we find the shortest one that works, but I could see that falling apart pretty quickly.

Comment: from each waypoint calculate distance to next point, if distance is greater tahn current charge, dynamically add a new waypoint for the closest charger...

Comment: So that was my first thought, but sometimes you have to go a roundabout way along a route you wouldn't normally take. I don't think just searching for the nearest charger would work for all situations, especially if there isn't a charger nearby.

Comment: It's unclear how many of these "optional" waypoints are actually necessary: you give an upper bound ("I don't need to stop at every one") but no lower bound.  So why not skip them all?  They're optional, after all.

Comment: Well the actual definitions are much more complex, it's not just a distance or number thing, but it's affected by elevation, speed, vehicle weight, etc. One set of circumstances might need a route where each leg can be 250 miles, and another set of circumstances might require each leg can only be 80 miles long (and may not have a valid route because of this).

Comment: Well, those actual definitions, or some simple approximation of them, *need to be in your question*, otherwise my trivial answer answers it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Construct a directed graph. The waypoints are the nodes, and you put a directed weighted edge from waypoint A to waypoint B if the distance can be covered by a fully charged car. Then you need to find the *shortest* path in a weighted directed graph.

Comment: This was super helpful. I think I can use a Directed Graph library to assist in building the graph, calculate the weights using the amount of energy required in the route, then find the path that uses the least amount of energy.